# String to Dictionary conversion in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
json_string = '{"list":[{"issues":{"first_name": "Guido", "last_name":"Rossum"},"issues":{"first_name": "sss", "last_name":"andsk"}}]}'
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
print(parsed_json)
```

The response in dict format for this is :

```
{'list':[{'issues':{'last_name':'andsk','first_name':'sss'}}]}'
```

Whereas I want the response to be:

```
{'list':[{'issues':{'last_name':'Rossum','first_name': 'Guido'},{'issues':{'last_name':'andsk','first_name':'sss'}}]}'
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Maybe fixing the typos in the json_string will help (you have misplaced `{}`s).

Comment: Thank you so much.. It is working now:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @spectras pointed it out right you need to change like this

```
json_string = '''{"list":[
            {"issues":{"first_name": "Guido", "last_name":"Rossum"}},
            {"issues":{"first_name": "sss", "last_name":"andsk"}} ]
            }'''
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
print(parsed_json)
```

Hope it may help !

Comment: Thank you. Got it to work:)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add on to [@sumit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37723320/4428725) as to why the code did not work. The problem is that Python dictionaries can only have one of each key. In this case, you have two equal keys (`"issues"`) contained in one dictionary:

```
{
    "list":[
        {
        # This part here
            "issues": {
                "first_name": "Guido",
                "last_name":"Rossum"
            },
            "issues": {
                "first_name": "sss",
                "last_name":"andsk"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So python will override the first value with the second value, hence, you only get one key and value in you end product.